# Setting data in LWC lightning datatable isnt working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, debugging, lwr

I have a lightning datatable

ecxTerritories.html

```
//random divs

<!-- this code below works

      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-m-bottom_medium  acc-info" lwc:if={selectedAccount}>
                    <div class="slds-p-around_medium selected-acc">
                        <p class="small">{labels.selectedDistrictName}</p> 
                        <h3>{selectedAccount.districtName}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-m-bottom_medium slds-m-horizontal_x-small divider"></div>
                    <div class="slds-m-horizontal_medium slds-m-bottom_medium add-acc-info">
                        <div class="slds-p-bottom_medium selected-acc">
                            <p class="slds-m-bottom_xx-small small">{labels.selectedDistrictNumber}</p> 
                            <h3>{selectedAccount.districtNumber}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="selected-acc">
                            <p class="slds-m-bottom_xx-small small">{labels.selectedDistrictTag}</p> 
                            <h3>{selectedAccount.tag}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
   -->

// Issue below
  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_12-of-12 slds-m-top_large tabset">
                    <lightning-tabset class="tab-account-picker ecx-tabs ecx-tabs-mobile">                    
                            <c-ecx-account-picker-custom-datatable 
                                key-field="id" 
                                data={territoriesData} 
                                columns={territoryColumns} 
                                max-row-selection=1 
                                resize-column-disabled
                                selected-rows={selectedRows} 
                                onrowaction={handleRowAction} 
                                onrowselection={handleRowSelection} 
                                onsort={onHandleSort}
                                sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                                default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}
                                sorted-by={sortedBy} 
                                column-widths-mode="auto"
                            >
                            </c-ecx-account-picker-custom-datatable>                         
                    </lightning-tabset>
                </div>
```

The ecx-Custom Datatable below

```
<template>
</template>
```

JS

```
import LightningDatatable from "lightning/datatable";
import ecxCustomImage from "./ecxCustomImage.html";


export default class EcxAccountPickerCustomDatatable extends LightningDatatable {

    static customTypes = {
        customImage : {
            template: ecxCustomImage,
            typeAttributes: ['title']
        }
    }
}
```

this is how Im populating data in territoriesData and territoryColumns

territoryConfig.js

```
const territoryColumns = [
    { label: 'Territory Name', fieldName: 'accountName', sortable :true, },
    { label: 'Territory Number', fieldName: 'address'},
    { label: 'Representative', fieldName: 'accountNumber'},
];

export {
    
    territoryColumns
    
}
```

The main JS file

ecxTerritories.JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import {    
    
    territoryColumns,
    
} from "./ecxTerritoryConfig";
// import various labels
export default class EcxTerritories extends LightningElement {

masterDataSet = [];
territoriesData = [];
@track resultSizePerPage;
@track totalResultSize;
@track recordPerPage = 10;
 @track numberofpages;

territoryColumns = territoryColumns;

    connectedCallback(){
     this.fetchAccounts();
      
    }

 fetchAccounts(){

 const dataR = [
            {   
                id: 1,
                territoryName: 'IS100',
                territoryNumber: 'IS100',
                representative: 'District'
            },
            {   
                id: 2,
                territoryName: 'IS102',
                territoryNumber: 'IS102',
                representative: 'District'
            },
         // similar 12 elements in this
];
this.displayFilteredData(dataR);
}

    


displayFilteredData(result){
        console.log('data hardcoded is', result);
        this.masterDataSet = this.convertToObject(result);
        console.log('masterdata is', this.masterDataSet);
        this.setRecordDataToView(this.masterDataSet);
        this.totalResultSize = this.masterDataSet.length;
    }

 setRecordDataToView(dataSet){

        let finalDataSet;
        if(dataSet?.length > this.recordPerPage){
            let pageData;
            let initialIndex = (this.pageNum - 1) * this.recordPerPage;
            let finalIndex = ((this.pageNum - 1) * this.recordPerPage) + this.recordPerPage
            pageData = dataSet.slice(initialIndex, finalIndex);
            finalDataSet = pageData;
        } else {
            finalDataSet = dataSet;
        }
        
            this.territoriesData = finalDataSet;   // Im populating the data here
            this.resultSizePerPage = this.accountsData?.length;
    
        this.numberofpages = Math.ceil(dataSet?.length/this.recordPerPage);
}

    convertToObject(returnValue){
        let arr=[];
        this.accountSet = returnValue;
        console.log('the result in Conv is',this.accountSet);
        this.accountSet.forEach(item =>{
            if(item != null){
                console.log('Inside iteration', item)
                let obj ={};
                obj.id = item.id;
                obj.territoryName = item.territoryName;
              
                obj.territoryNumber = item.territoryNumber;
                obj.representative = item.representative;
                arr.push(obj);
           
        }
        })
        console.log('array returned after conversion', arr);
        return arr;        
    }


}
```

Surprisingly Im getting the values in the data in the console logs applied in the JS above
[image]

[image]

But I am unable to understand in the setRecordDataToView method why the line below

```
this.territoriesData = finalDataSet;   // not working
```

I am confused. Also the Experience Builder is throwing the below error
[image]

I have applied debug logs in browser JS as well but unable to understand what is the issue. The site works in Experience Portal and the User has all the necessary permissions needed. Access is not the issue here. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE: I resolved the issue**. Problem was with the fieldNames in the territory Columns. they were accountname,address and accountNumber. They needed to be territoryName, territoryNumber and representative. The fieldNames in the lightning-datatable need to be exactly as per the fieldnames of the data that is populated to the table

Comment: You are unlikely to get help from anyone since you are not using the standard datatable component, but a custom one (ecx-account-picker-custom-datatable) instead. If you are able to show the source for that component, or switch to the standard datatable, you'll get a bigger chance to be helped.

Comment: updated the component